# Use NGINX to limit multiple IPs generated by proxy chain to just client IP?

Tags: nginx, ip, reverse-proxy, haproxy, varnish

I’m running NGINX (version 1.17.3) as the last step in a system set up like this:

Client -> HAProxy (SSL termination) -> Varnish -> NGINX

It works well, but if I look through the NGINX logs I see *both* the client IP and 127.0.0.1, separated by a comma. The 127.0.0.1, which comes second in the chain, is Varnish.

Is there a way of telling NGINX to ignore this second address, so that:

`1.2.3.4, 127.0.0.1`

becomes just

`1.2.3.4`

?

My problem is not that the second IP is showing up in the logs — I don’t care about that per se — but that it passes it through to certain pieces of software running behind NGINX and messes with them if they are expecting a single IP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to tackle this issue is by using the [PROXY protocol](https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/doc/proxy-protocol.txt) to connect between HAProxy and Varnish.

This protocol stores client connection information in the TCP package and transports this information along the various hops.

The requirement is that your proxy servers support this protocol. Luckily Varnish and HAProxy do.

For HAProxy it's a matter of adding `send-proxy-v2` as an extra attribute to your backend definition.

For Varnish you'll need to ensure a listening port is opened that supports PROXY.

### HAProxy example configuration

Here's an oversimplified HAProxy example configuration that supports `send-proxy-v`:

```
defaults
    mode    http

frontend http-in-proxy
    bind *:80
    default_backend servers-proxy

backend servers-proxy
    server server1-proxy varnish.example.com:8443 send-proxy-v2
```

For the sake of simplicity I'm not terminating TLS, but I'm only sending plain HTTP to Varnish over the PROXY protocol.

### Varnish proxy example

And here's an example of an extra listening port that is opened with PROXY support:

```
varnishd -a :80 -a :8443,PROXY -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,2g
```

As you can see, the regular HTTP port is `80`, whereas the PROXY port is `8443`. The HAProxy configuration also refers to that port.

### What about that X-Forwarded-For header?

Once you have successfully set up the PROXY protocol, you can now benefit from an accurate `X-Forwarded-For` header.

Varnish will use the value that it gets from the PROXY protocol and no longer needs to chain the `X-Forwarded-For` values.

If the IP address of the client connecting to HAProxy is `1.2.3.4`, the `X-Forwarded-For` header in Nginx will be `X-Forwarded-For: 1.2.3.4`.

### Added bonus: TLS information.

The PROXY protocol doesn't only store the original client IP address, it also stores information about the request protocol.

Here's an example of the `proxy` VMOD that is used to determine whether or not the original connection was made over HTTP or HTTPS:

```
vcl 4.1;

import proxy;

sub vcl_recv {
    if (proxy.is_ssl()) {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "https";
    } else {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "http";
    }
}

sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
}
```

> Note: this example will also creating protocol-based cache variations by adding the value of the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header to the hash of the cached object.

Here's another example where we extract more TLS information using the PROXY protocol:

```
vcl 4.1;
import proxy;

sub vcl_deliver {
    set resp.http.alpn = proxy.alpn();
    set resp.http.authority = proxy.authority();
    set resp.http.ssl = proxy.is_ssl();
    set resp.http.ssl-version = proxy.ssl_version();
    set resp.http.ssl-cipher = proxy.ssl_cipher();
    set resp.http.client-has-cert-sess = proxy.client_has_cert_sess();
    set resp.http.client-has-cert-conn = proxy.client_has_cert_conn();   
}
```

### Backup plan

I hope I convinced you that the PROXY protocol is very powerful. However, if you're not planning to use the PROXY protocol, you can still extract the first value of the `X-Forwarded-For` header in your VCL code.

Here's how you can do this in VCL:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = regsub(req.http.X-Forwarded-For,"^([^,]+)(,[^,]+)*","\1");
}
```

This value will then be presented to your Nginx server in a ready-to-use format.

Comment: Thank you for this incredible response, I appreciate it.

I tried the first option, but it still gave me two IPs. This time, though, instead of one being the right IP and the other being 127.0.0.1, both were the right IP, separated by a comma. Any idea why?

The backup plan worked first time.

Comment: @Charles Maybe it's because you have an `option forwarfor` somewhere in your HAProxy configuration. Try removing that and test again.

Comment: Thank you. That was it. I removed it, and it worked. This, though, raised another question. I have Varnish as the *primary* server in HAProxy, but as a *backup*, HAProxy will send visitors directly to the NGINX server. By removing the `option forwardfor`, I now don't get any IP addresses passed through when HAProxy sends traffic to the backup (i.e. directly to NGINX). Is there any way I can make HAProxy do what it was doing with the `option forwardfor` variable but only at the server level?

Comment: @Charles Maybe set the X-Forwarded-For header on the non-Varnish backend instead of setting it globally.